# Gradle exception: "There must be one branch ID(.bid) file in the root dir of the project"

Tags: android, exception, gradle

I try to run project which includes multiple modules. During project configuration on build step (`app` module) gradle throws exceptions as below:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There must be one branch ID(.bid) file in the root dir of the project
    at com.sec.sm.gradle.SecTask$_closure1.doCall(SecTask.groovy:124)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:63)
    at org.gradle.listener.ActionBroadcast.execute(ActionBroadcast.java:39)
    ... 60 more
```

**Gradle Version: 2.2.1** (update to the latest ver. is not an option)

Unfortunately, I didn't find any information in gradle documentation/source code related to mentioned exception. Thanks for any help

Comment: Create empty text file with name .bid and keep it in root directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @chait mentioned in the comment, project was missing `0.bid` file which should be created by IDE in root directory.